# Uniqueness of Solutions to First-Order, Linear, Homogeneous, Boundary-Value PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation, linear-pde

Consider a homogeneous, linear, first-order PDE

$$L u \equiv \left( \sum_{i = 1}^d f^i(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + c(x) \right) u(x) = 0$$

on some compact domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$.  Obviously this system always has $u = 0$ as a solution; my question is what sorts of conditions on the coefficients $f^i(x)$ and $c(x)$ are sufficient in order to guarantee that the zero solution is unique subject to the boundary condition $u|_{\partial \Omega} = 0$.

I know that well-posedness of first-order PDEs is usually studied via the method of characteristics, but as I understand that's typically useful in thinking of the PDE as an initial value problem in which boundary conditions are specified on an initial-value surface and evolved from there.  Because here I'm treating the system as a Dirichlet problem, the inhomogenous problem $Lu = g$, $u|_{\partial \Omega} = h$ may not in general be well-posed; but that's OK because I just care about uniqueness of the zero solution to the homogeneous problem.

I have one partial result from Oleinik and Radkevic (https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781468489675), which consider second-order linear PDEs with nonnegative characteristic form, of which the equation I gave above is a special case (since its characteristic form is identically zero).  Then from e.g. Theorem 1.6.2 of this book I can conclude that the zero solution is unique if $c^* < 0$ in $\Omega \cup \partial \Omega$, where $c^* \equiv c - \sum_{i = 1}^d \partial_i f^i$ is the zero-derivative term of the adjoint $L^*$ of $L$.  But because the operator $L$ I care about is genuinely a first-order operator, while the condition $c^* < 0$ comes from considering second-order operators, I imagine there must be much more general sufficient conditions for the uniqueness of the zero solution than just $c^* < 0$.

Comment: I don't know how useful this is (but I have nothing smarter to say - this seems like a tough problem), but uniqueness of solutions for boundary value problems can be sometimes proven using the method of energies. Maybe you can think of a method of constructing an energy functional that would fit a large family of differential operators $L$ which could be used to prove uniqueness? Perhaps you could find a sufficient criterion for a differential operator to satisfy in order to 'fit' the energy functional you constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method of characteristics looks like the right way to solve this.  Along paths that satisfy ${\rm d}x_i/{\rm d}t = f_i(\vec{x})$, one finds $u(\vec{x}(t))$ evolves according to ${\rm d}u/{\rm d}t = -c u$.  If the path terminates at $\partial\Omega$, then $u(x) = 0$ along the whole path.  This leads to our first *necessary condition* for the existence of a nonzero solution:

(1) $\exists$ path $\vec{x}(t)$ satisfying ${\rm d}x_i/{\rm d}t = f_i(\vec{x})$ with origin and terminus (limits as $t \rightarrow \pm\infty$) in the interior of $\Omega$.

For a continuous $u(\vec{x})$, the value of $u(\vec{x}(t))$ cannot diverge when $t \rightarrow \pm\infty$.  Excepting a set of measure zero, all paths $\vec{x}(t)$ start at a repulsor and end at an attractor (rather than, say, a saddle point).  Two more *necessary conditions* for the existence of a nonzero solution are therefore:

(2) $c < 0$ at $\vec{x}(-\infty)$

(3) $c > 0$ at $\vec{x}(+\infty)$

Except for a set of measure zero, we can probably assume these inequalities are strict, i.e. $c < 0$ and $c > 0$, respectively (convergence is possible for $c = 0$ but not guaranteed, depending on derivative terms).  With the strict inequalities, conditions (1-3) are also *sufficient* for nonzero solutions $u(\vec{x})$ to exist.  That can be seen as follows:

Starting with a point $\vec{x}_0$ along the path $\vec{x}(t)$, define a size-$\epsilon$ cross section (orthogonal to the streamlines of ${\rm d}x_i/{\rm d}t = f_i(\vec{x})$) and posit that $u(\vec{x})$ varies smoothly from $u(x_0) = 1$ to $u = 0$ at the boundaries of the cross section.  The value of $u(\vec{x})$ along the "past" and "future" of this cross section is obtained by propagating along the characteristics using ${\rm d}u/{\rm d}t = -c u$.  All these characteristics originate from the same repulsor (where $u = 0$) and terminate at the same attractor (also where $u = 0$).  Fill in the rest of $\Omega$ with the null solution $u = 0$.  Thus we have constructed a nonzero, continuous-valued solution to the PDE.

There are a bunch of singular edge cases where the necessary and sufficient conditions don't coincide, i.e. if $\lVert f \rVert = u = 0$ at the same point (fixable by rescaling $f$ and $u$), if $\lVert f\rVert = 0$ over an open subset of $\Omega$, if $\lVert f\rVert = 0$ on the boundary $\partial\Omega$, if $c = 0$ at $\vec{x}(\pm\infty)$.  In the space of possible functions $(\vec{f}, u)$, these singular cases only occur in a set of measure zero, so are not very interesting.  Almost everywhere, conditions (1-3) are *both* necessary and sufficient.

Putting this another way, we can say (almost everywhere) that *the zero solution is unique* if:

> $\forall$ paths $\vec{x}(t)$ satisfying ${\rm d}x_i/{\rm d}t = f_i(\vec{x})$ with origin and terminus in the interior of $\Omega$,
>
> $c > 0$ at $\vec{x}(-\infty)$ **or** $c < 0$ at $\vec{x}(+\infty)$.

Coming back to your condition $c^* < 0$: Note that $\partial_i f^i < 0$ at attractors (this always holds, regardless of whether it's a node, limit cycle, toroid, chaotic attractor, etc.).  Therefore, if $c^* < 0$ on $\Omega$, it follows that $c = c^* + \partial_i f^i < 0$ at all of the attractors.  Therefore, the second condition above is always satisfied when $c^* < 0$.  The condition above is the more general sufficient (and necessary) condition for uniqueness (with the caveats noted above).

Since **any** dynamical system can be represented by ${\rm d}x_i/{\rm d}t = f_i(\vec{x})$ and dynamical systems can be really, really complicated, the general condition can be hard to work with, so more specific conditions like $c^* < 0$ might be more useful.

Also, defining the value of $c$ is tricky when the attractor / repulsor isn't a point.  Taking the average over limit cycles is straightforward, chaotic attractors less so (ergodic theory).

Comment: Thanks!  This is extremely clear, and gave me a much better understanding of the method of characteristics than I'd been able to get from quickly skimming the literature.  I notice you treat the $c = 0$ case as an exception; do you know what can be said when $c = 0$ everywhere in $\Omega$?  (Besides requiring that there simply be no paths $\vec{x}(t)$ satisfying $dx_i/dt = f_i(\vec{x})$  with origin and terminus in the interior of $\Omega$.)

Comment: Naively going off of your answer, I would think that continuity of $u$ in the $c = 0$ case would require $u$ to vanish at any origins and/or termini in the interior of $\Omega$, so that the zero solution must always be the unique one.  But I might be being too fast, especially if there are attractors or repulsors that aren't points.

Comment: More precisely, since $u = 0$ along any path that reaches $\partial \Omega$, I would think that continuity of $u$ in the $c = 0$ case would require $u$ to also vanish along any path whose origin and terminus can both be reached by paths that hit $\partial \Omega$.  But I don't know how to deal with paths whose origin and terminus cannot be reached in such a way.

Comment: For $c = 0$ everywhere, the PDE tells us that $u(\vec{x})$ is constant along characteristics.  Unless $\partial_i f^i = 0$ for any open subset of $\Omega$, $\Omega$ can be divided into (I think) a countable number of basins of attraction.  If $u = 0$ at the attractor, it is zero in the entire basin.  If $u = 0$ in one basin, it is zero in all neighboring basins (by continuity).  Since the basins are connected, and $u = 0$ on the boundary, it must be zero anywhere.

Comment: But there is one pathological case where this doesn't work: if $f^i$ is Hamiltonian ($\partial_i f^i = 0$) over any finite subset of $\Omega$.  Then there are regions of $\Omega$ that are *not*  basins of attraction.  Consider a rotational flow $\vec{f} = r \hat{\phi}$ on a unit disc.  The PDE tells us $u(r, \phi)$ is independent of $\phi$, but it can depend on $r$, so nonzero solutions exist.

Comment: This extremely useful, thanks!  One more clarification: I understand why the lack of basins of attraction means that nonzero solutions will exist.  But why does that require $f^i$ to be Hamiltonian?  After all, $f^i$ and $\tilde{f}^i \equiv g(x) f^i$ have the same characteristics (for $g$ some everywhere-nonzero function on $\Omega$), and hence if there are characteristics generated by $f^i$ that do not have basins of attraction, the same must be true of characteristics generated by $\tilde{f}^i$.  But if $\partial_i f^i = 0$, then $\partial_i \tilde{f}^i \neq 0$ in general.

Comment: To use your example, consider e.g. the flow $\vec{f} = (1+x^2) r \hat{\phi} = (-y(1+x^2), x(1+x^2))$; the PDE still says that $u(r,\phi)$ must be constant in $\phi$ but can depend arbitrarily on $r$, yet $\partial_i f^i = -2 x y$ only vanishes on the axes (which I would not consider a finite subset of the unit disk).  Conversely, consider the flow field $\vec{f} = (-y^2, x^2)$; this flow has $\partial_i f^i = 0$, and yet the line $y = -x$ is a basin of attraction/repulsion for all characteristics, so the zero solution is unique (still working on the unit disk).

Comment: Good point.  Hamiltonian flow is a sufficient condition then, but not a necessary one.  I don't know what the general necessary and sufficient condition would be (besides what was said about basins of attraction).